# USR-TCP232-T2: Basic config and port config commands returns 0xBE 0x45 (Error)

Tags: c

This is my first time using the USR-TCP232-T2 module (TTL-Ethernet converter).
My project is to config and Tx\Rx with the module by the serial port (not the LAN port).
When I send basic parameters config command or port parameters config command, the result is 0xBE 0x45 (Error).

Explanation:
During initialization I send read configuration command.
The module returns 137 bytes as follows:

```
0x55 0xb                              - ducSequenceNum[2];
0x00                                  - ucCRC;
0x00                                  - ucVersion;
0x00                                  - UnknownParameter;
0x00                                  - ucFlags_1;
0x00 0x00                             - usLocationURLPort[2];
0x50 0x00                             - usHTTPServerPort[2];
0x00                                  - ucUserFlag;
0x07 0x00 0xa8 0xc0                   - ulStaticIP[4];
0x01 0x00 0xa8 0xc0                   - ulGatewayIP[4];
0x00 0xff 0xff 0xff                   - ulSubnetMask[4];
0x55, 0x53, 0x52, 0x2d, 0x54, 0x43, 0x50, 0x32
0x33, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x54, 0x32, 0x00    - ucModName[14];
0x00, 0x00                            - ProtocolReserved[2];
0x61, 0x64, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x00    - username[6];
0x61, 0x64, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x00    - password[6];
0x00                                  - ucNetSendTime;
0x01, 0x00                            - uiId[2];
0x80                                  - ucIdType;
0xd8, 0xb0, 0x4c, 0xf9, 0xb4, 0x8d    - mac_addrs[6];
0xde, 0xde, 0x43, 0xd0                - DNS_Gateway_IP[4];
0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00                - ucReserved_1[4];
0x00, 0xC2, 0x01, 0x00                - ulBaudRate[4];
0x08                                  - ucDataSize;
0x01                                  - ucParity;
0x01                                  - ucStopBits;
0x00                                  - ucFlowControl;
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00                - ulTelnetTimeout[4];
0x8C, 0x4E                            - usTelnetLocalPort[2];
0x2a, 0x20                            - usTelnetRemotePort[2];
0x31, 0x39, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36,                            
0x38, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x32, 0x00,
0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00    - uiTelnetURL[30];
0xc9, 0x00, 0xa8, 0xc0                - ulTelnetIPAddr[4];
0x20                                  - ucFlags_2;
0x01                                  - ucWorkMode;
0x00                                  - HTPucFlags;
0x04                                  - tc_number;
0x10, 0x0e                            - uiPackLen[2];
0x00                                  - ucPackTime;
0x00                                  - ucTimeCount;
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00          - ucReserved_2[5];
0xac 0x13 0x01 0x57                   - Current_IP[4];
0xb1                                  - Version;
```

Now, When I send Basic Parameters config Command, same as in the received configuration:

```
0x55                                  - Start byte
0xBE                                  - Basic parameters command code  0x00                                  - ucSequenceNum       
0x00                                  - ucCRC               
0x00,                                 - ucVersion           
0x00,                                 - ucFlags - DHCP
0x00, 0x00,                           - usLocationURLPort[2]
0x50, 0x00,                           - usHTTPServerPort[2] 
0x00,                                 - ucUserFlag          
0x07, 0x00, 0xA8, 0xC0,               - ulStaticIP[4]       
0x01, 0x00, 0xA8, 0xC0,               - ulGatewayIP[4]      
0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,               - ulSubnetMask[4]     
0x55, 0x53, 0x52, 0x2d, 0x54,
0x43, 0x50, 0x32, 0x33, 0x32,
0x2d, 0x54, 0x32, 0x00,               - ucModName[14]                     
0x00, 0x00,                           - ProtocolReserved[2] 
0x61, 0x64, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x00,   - username[6]
0x61, 0x64, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x00,   - password[6]
0x00,                                 - ucNetSendTime       
0x01, 0x00,                           - uiId[2]             
0x80,                                 - ucIdType            
0xd8, 0xb0, 0x4c, 0xf9, 0xb4, 0x8d,   - mac_addrs[6]        
0xde, 0xde, 0x43, 0xd0,               - DNSGatewayIP[4]     
0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00                - ucReserved[4]       
0xFF                                  - CheckSum
```

The USR-TCP232-T2 module returns 0xBE 0x45 which indicates some error.

Or, when I send Port Parameters config Command, same as in the received configuration:

```
0x55                                  - Start byte
0xBF                                  - Port parameters command code        
0x00, 0xC2, 0x01, 0x00,               - ulBaudRate[4] - 115200 bps        
0x08,                                 - ucDataSize           
0x01,                                 - ucParity           
0x01,                                 - ucStopBits           
0x00,                                 - ucFlowControl        
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,               - ulTelnetTimeout[4]   
0x8C, 0x4E,                           - usTelnetLocalPort[2]
0x2a, 0x20,                           - usTelnetRemotePort[2]
0x31, 0x39, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36,                            
0x38, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x32, 0x00,
0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   - uiTelnetURL[30]                
0xc9, 0x00, 0xa8, 0xc0,               - ulTelnetIPAddr[4]    
0x20,                                 - ucFlags              
0x01,                                 - ucWorkMode           
0x00,                                 - HTPucFlags           
0x04,                                 - tc_number            
0x10, 0x0e,                           - uiPackLen[2]         
0x00,                                 - ucPackTime           
0x00,                                 - ucTimeCount          
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00          - ucReserved[5]        
0xBD                                  - CheckSum
```

The USR-TCP232-T2 module returns 0xBE 0x45 which indicates some error.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
The code to send the command was:

```
u8 BasicSettingCom[] = {0x55, 0xBE, &basicParamsStruct, checkSum};
.
.
SendDataToClient((u8*)BasicSettingCom, Length);
```

So the pointer of basicParamsStruct was sent and not its content.

Now the code to send the command is:

```
const u8 BasicSettingCmd[] = {0x55, 0xBE};
.
.
SendDataToClient((u8*)BasicSettingCmd, cmdLen);
SendDataToClient((u8*)basicParamsStruct , dataLen);
SendByteToClient(checkSum);
```

and it works fine.